# How to write more than one statement in if statement in CPN ML?

Tags: ml

I want to update the value of two variables in an if statement in *ML*. I used this code:

```
fun next (row, start) =
  let
    val b = 1
    val continue = false
  in
    while (start <= 8) do 
    (
      if condition  
      then 
        b = start 
        continue=false
      else 
        b = b
    )
  end;
```

But this code has errors and I have no idea why. More generally, what is the syntax of blocks in *ML*?

Answer (score 2):

Variables in pure functional programming are actually not *variable*. That is, once you assigned a value to a variable you cannot change it (only shadow the variable by a new one having the same name). If you really need/want mutability you can use the `ref` type (for mutable references, whose assignment is `:=`, not `=`, and which are dereferenced via prefix `!`).

As for block structure in *ML*, just use parentheses `(` and `)` and separate statements by semi-colons `;`.

You could use the following code:

```
fun next (row, start) =
  let
   val b = ref 1;
   val continue = ref false;
  in
    while (!start <= 8) do (
      if !continue  
        then (
          b := !start;
          continue := false
        ) else ( b := !b)
    )
end;
```

where I replaced `condition` (which is not defined in your post) by `continue`. I'm just saying that the above code compiles though, not that it makes a lot of sense.